# Find basis of subspace in $\Bbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is my first encounter with subspaces, and even though I get the concept, I am stuck with this problem. Could anyone give me a hint how to get started?

The question is as follows:

Find a basis for the subspace $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$, where
$$
V = \{[a+b−2c, a+b−2c+d, −2a+2b+4c−d, b+d]^T  \mid \ a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$

Comment: Start by breaking up $V$ into the sum of 4 vectors where each one contains only one a's, b's, c's and d's respectively

Comment: A hint? Determine the transformation matrix that maps the coordinates $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ to the subspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Let $x$ be a generic vector in $V$, and write it in the form
$$x=av_1+bv_2+cv_3+dv_4$$
where $v_1, \dots, v_4$ are obtained from collecting coefficients of $a, \dots, d$ in each slot of $x$. For instance,
$$v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-2\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$
Clearly, $V$ is spanned by $v_1, \dots, v_4$, so $V$ is at most $4$ dimensional. (This was clear from the beginning since $V$ sits in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Now your job is to determine if $\{v_1, \dots, v_4\}$ is linearly independent. If yes, it is a basis for $V$; otherwise you should be able to shrink it to a basis by tossing dependent vectors.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}  (a+b−2c, a+b−2c+d, −2a+2b+4c−d, b+d) &= (a,a,-2a,0) + (b,b,2b,b) + (-2c,-2c,4c,0) + (0,d,-d,d) \\ &=a(1,1,-2,0)+b(1,1,2,1)+c(-2-2,4,0) + d (0,1,-1,1). \end{align}$$