# How to show that something is a basis of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have the following question in my homework.

Show that the following

\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}

is a basis of the subspace of $R^{2}$ defined by the following universe

\begin{equation*}
U = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & c \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*} where a, b, and c are elements of R.

In other words the subspace of upper triangular matrices.

This is something I need to know how to prove for test and etc, but when I see this I dont know how to approach it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can show they are a basis by 2 steps. 1. Show they are linearly independent. 2. Show all elements of U can be written as a linearly combination of those basis. [Reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1014325/find-basis-of-subspace-in-r4)

Comment: @AbelWong I would add: show all the elements are in $U$. Otherwise, one might take a basis for a larger space and successfully verify your two steps.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Thanks for notice, I missed 1 step.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you have to check that they satisfy two conditions.

$1.$ The list is linearly independent. You have to show that if for any scalars $a_1, a_2, a_3\in R$ $$a_1\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}+a_2\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}+a_3\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ then $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$

$2.$ Let $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix}$ be an arbitrary matrix in $U$. You have to pick scalars $c_1,c_2,c_3$ such that $$c_1\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}+c_2\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}+c_3\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix}$$

Then you would have proven that it is a basis of the vector space in question.

Edit: As pointed out in the comment below by Arturo Magidin, you have to make sure that the vectors in question are elements of the subspace.

Comment: There is an additional condition: verify all vectors/matrices lie in your subspace. Note $\{E_{11},E_{12},E_{21},E_{22}\}$ satisfies both conditions (it is linearly independent, and every vector in $U$ can be written as a linear combination of these vectors) yet that is not a basis for $U$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, a very important point. I forgot about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The space you are interested in is $U = \{
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & c \\
\end{pmatrix}|a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

A basis of a space is a set of linearly independent vectors in $U$ which *spans* the set $U$, what this means is $span\{v_1,v_2,v_3\} = \{a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3| a_1,a_2,a_3\in\mathbb{R}\} = U$. Here $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are called scalars.

From here can you see that:

1. Indeed the 3 vectors you mentioned span the space $U$?
2. The 3 vectors are linearly independent?

As a test can you come up with another basis for $U$

Comment: A set of linearly independent vectors *in $U$* that span $U$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Of course! Edited